# React-Rails bind returns not a function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I was working on my app. And as I tried to bind my function within the jQuery ajax call it's always saying `Uncaught TypeError: this.addNewAppointment is not a function`

Here's my full `Appointments.jsx` file:

```
import React from 'react';
import Appointment from './Appointment';
import AppointmentForm from './AppointmentForm';
import AppointmentsList from './AppointmentsList';

class Appointments extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            appointments: this.props.appointments,
            title: 'Put your event title',
            appointment_time: 'When would this happen?'
        };

        this.handleUserInput = this.handleUserInput.bind(this);
        this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);
        this.addNewAppointment = this.addNewAppointment.bind(this);
    }

    handleUserInput(obj_value){
        this.setState(obj_value);
    }

    handleFormSubmit(){
        let appointment = JSON.stringify({ 
            title: this.state.title, 
            appointment_time: this.state.appointment_time 
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: '/appointments',
            type: "POST",
            data: appointment, 
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function(data){
                this.addNewAppointment(data)
            }
        });
    }

    addNewAppointment(appointment){
        let appointments = React.addons.update(this.state.appointments, { $push: [appointment] } );
        this.setState({ appointments: appointments.sort((a, b) => (new Date(a.appointment_time) - new Date(b.appointment_time))
        )})
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <AppointmentForm title={this.state.title} 
                    appointment_time={this.state.appointment_time} 
                    onUserInput={this.handleUserInput}
                    onFormSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}
                />
                <AppointmentsList appointments={this.props.appointments} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Appointments;
```

I am calling my bind on the constructor:

```
this.addNewAppointment = this.addNewAppointment.bind(this);
```

It's on the ajax call where I tried to call the `addNewAppointment` function:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/appointments',
    type: "POST",
    data: appointment, 
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(data){
        this.addNewAppointment(data)
    }
});
```

But when I tried to add a new item I am getting this error:

```
Appointments.jsx:38 Uncaught TypeError: this.addNewAppointment is not a function
        at Object.success (Appointments.jsx:38)
        at fire (jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:3233)
        at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:3363)
        at done (jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:9841)
        at XMLHttpRequest.callback (jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:10312)
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding the method `addNewAppointment` so that every time it is called, the execution context (i.e., the value of `this`) will be the `Appointments` instance.

This will guarantee that, no matter how the method is called, you will be able to access `this.state.appointments` and call `this.setState` inside the `addNewAppointment` method.

But that binding does not guarantee that every time you try to call the method with `this.addNewAppointment` the value of `this` will be the component instance. In the case you present, as the call to `$.ajax` creates a new execution context, when you call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/appointments',
    type: "POST",
    data: appointment, 
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(data){
        this.addNewAppointment(data)
    }
});
```

the execution context (the value of `this`) is not the component instance. To solve this you can do two things:

1. Define the success callback as an arrow function, that inherits the parent execution context:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/appointments',
    type: "POST",
    data: appointment, 
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: data => {
        this.addNewAppointment(data)
    }
});
```

2. Store the execution context when you know it is the component instance and then use that reference:

```
handleFormSubmit() {
    const self = this;
    const appointment = JSON.stringify({ 
        title: this.state.title, 
        appointment_time: this.state.appointment_time 
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: '/appointments',
        type: "POST",
        data: appointment, 
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function(data){
            self.addNewAppointment(data)
        }
    });
}
```